# Minecraft Server Port Forwarding

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, minecraft

I'm trying to host a Minecraft server from my Windows 10 PC. I had no problem whatsoever setting up the server itself, but i've been banging my head against the wall for three weeks now trying to get the port forwarding to work. I've set up a static IP. I've made sure the ports aren't being blocked. But still, nobody other than me can connect to the server and every port checker out there says my ports are blocked.

The only other explanation I can come up with is that my WiFi setup is a little unorthodox- We have a primary router upstairs with a cable running to a secondary router setup downstairs (that's the one i'm trying to use.) Could that possibly be it, and is there a solution if it is?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to port forward on both routers ...

Comment: Ok. I should add that the default gateway of both PCs takes me to the downstairs (secondary) router, while the public IP takes me to the primary router. is that normal?

Comment: Yes, if you have [double nat](https://kb.netgear.com/30186/What-is-Double-NAT)

Comment: ok, i have confirmed that i do have double nat